# how to resolve javax.mail.MessagingException in mail sending

Tags: android

Hello guys I am working with JavaMailApi I am trying to send emails from my app only. This question is already asked so many times and I have tried so many example and almost all were same but i cant resolve the exception of javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp-mail.outlook.com, port: 587
this is my code:

```
public class SendMail extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

//Declaring Variables
private Context context;
private Session session;

//Information to send email
private String email;
private String subject;
private String message;

//Progressdialog to show while sending email
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

//Class Constructor
public SendMail(Context context, String email, String subject, String message) {
    //Initializing variables
    this.context = context;
    this.email = email;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.message = message;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    //Showing progress dialog while sending email
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Sending message", "Please wait...", false, false);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    //Dismissing the progress dialog
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    //Showing a success message
    Toast.makeText(context, "Message Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    String prot = "smtp";
    final String user = Config.EMAIL;
    String to = Config.EMAIL;
    final String pass = Config.PASSWORD;
    String mailhost = "smtp-mail.outlook.com";

    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.put("mail." + prot + ".host", mailhost);
    props.put("mail." + prot + ".auth", "true");
    props.put("mail." + prot + ".starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail." + prot + ".port", "587");
    props.put("mail." + prot + ".ssl.enable", "false");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(user, pass);
                }
            });
    session.setDebug(true);

    try {
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse(to, false));

        msg.setSubject("TESTE ENVIO EMAIL");

        msg.setText("Teste de envio de email conteudo");

        msg.setHeader("X-Mailer", user);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());

        SMTPTransport t = (SMTPTransport) session.getTransport(prot);

        t.connect(mailhost, user, pass);

        t.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
        t.close();

        Log.d("------------", "done");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

please suggest me whats wrong with this code.
Thank you

Comment: Did you tried by changing *mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com"* ?

Comment: yes, i have already tried this too.

Comment: Try by changing the *port to 465* with using *mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com"*.

Comment: same exception with 465.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Please put this code in doInBackground method and try may be help you. it working for me

```
try {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", Constant.MAIL_SMTP_AUTH);
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", Constant.MAIL_SMTP_STARTTLS_ENABLE);
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", Constant.MAIL_SMTP_HOST);
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", Constant.MAIL_SMTP_PORT);
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                            return new PasswordAuthentication(Constant.SMTP_USER, Constant.SMTP_PASSWORD);
                        }
                    });
            message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(Constant.SMTP_FROM));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(Constant.SMTP_TO));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC,
                    InternetAddress.parse(Constant.SMTP_CC));
            message.setSubject(mSalesOrderNumber + "_Invoice");
            String messageStr = getString(R.string.msg_please_find_attached_invoice);
            MimeBodyPart messagePart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messagePart.setText(messageStr);
            MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            FileDataSource fileDataSource = new FileDataSource(filePath) {
                @Override
                public String getContentType() {
                    return "application/pdf";
                }
            };
            attachmentPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fileDataSource));
            attachmentPart.setFileName(filePath.getName());
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            multipart.addBodyPart(messagePart);
            multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);
            message.setContent(multipart);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: remove this line and try
  props.put("mail." + prot + ".ssl.enable", "false");

Comment: your solution is working no exception is arising but my mail box is empty.

Comment: Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail." + prot + ".host", mailhost);
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
            props.put("mail." + prot + ".ssl.enable", "false");

Comment: Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                            return new PasswordAuthentication(Config.EMAIL, Config.PASSWORD);
                        }
                    });

Comment: Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(Config.EMAIL));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(Config.EMAIL));
            message.setSubject("this is the testing subject");
            MimeBodyPart messagePart = new MimeBodyPart();
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            multipart.addBodyPart(messagePart);
            message.setContent(multipart);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }